# Upgrade Tridion 2009 SP1 CM Database to 2011 SP1

Tags: tridion

When performing pre-upgrade check for content manager database from Tridion 2009 SP1 to 2011 SP1 I recieve the following error in manager and log files.

Any clues?

```
<TdmLog DateCreated="2012-04-19T10:20:26" ApplicationVersion="6.1.0.996">
<Event DateTime="2012-04-19T10:20:26" Id="0" Type="1">
    <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
    <Description>Tridion Content Management Database Upgrade Analysis</Description>
    <Source>MainModule.ProcessScripts</Source>
</Event>
```

[image: DB Update Manager]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>` suggests that it's OK? I suspect that this is a success message, maybe double check with Customer Support.

Comment: During the pre-upgrade check it seems to flag warnings, but you are right error code 0.

Comment: Started the upgrade, lets see what happens :)

Answer (score 6):

Nuno is right. ErrorCode 0 means no errors, so pre-upgrade was successfully performed and found no issues. If there will be any issue found by pre-upgrade check then you will get error message popup and error code won't be 0.